# Unknown Select(?) of System Data Entity DbSet

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is something like this possible?  I am getting the below error.

```
    db.SomeTable.Add(new SomeTable()
    {
        GuidId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = db.AnotherTable.Select(x => x.Name.Where(x.Id == localVariable.Id))
    }

  );
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Unknown Select(?) of System Data Entity DbSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` returns an `IEnumerable`, not an individual record. You would needed to add a `.First()` call to grab just one record. Entity Framework thinks you're trying to put a list into a single field.

Furthermore, your use of `Where()` is incorrect. `Where` also returns an `IEnumerable`, and can only be applied on to an `IEnumerable`. Think of it as a way to filter a list.

Here's how to do what I think you're asking for:

```
Name = db.AnotherTable.First(x => x.id == someId).Name
```

Comment: Also `Where` takes a lambda or function.

Comment: Right you are! Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
Name = db.AnotherTable
    .First(x => x.Id == localVariable.Id)
    .Name;
```

The steps of this are:

1. Go into list of items in `AnotherTable`
2. Find the first item where the `Id` of the item is equal to `localVariable.Id`
3. Set your variable equal to the `Name` property of the item you found

You can also use `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, and `SingleOrDefault()`.